# How do I access the service definition for a specific SharePoint list web service?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a problem accessing the web service ?wsdl for SharePoint lists, although I can see the list of operations.

For example, for the following URLS:

`://team/sites/test/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` - returns a list of operations

`://team/sites/test/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL` - returns the wsdl document

`://team/sites/test/Lists/TestList1/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` - returns a list of operations

`://team/sites/test/Lists/TestList1/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL` - returns a 404 error (example of full error pasted below).

I've checked on a few SP installations and I'm seeing the same behaviour on all of them, I've also tried logging on to the web server as admin and calling the pages and I get the same result each time. I've also checked that DisableLoopbackCheck is set to 1 in the registry.

Is it the case that there is no WSDL available for specific lists, just for the generic list type i.e. you get the WSDL from /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL and access the actual service via ///_vti_bin/Lists.asmx, or have I got the wrong end of the stick here?

Any help gratefuly accepted.

Error Text:

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://team/sites/test/Lists/Repairs%20Services%20Customer%20Satisfaction%20TEST/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found. Metadata contains
>   a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://team/sites/test/Lists/Repairs Services Customer Satisfaction
>   TEST/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl'. The HTTP request is unauthorized with
>   client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header
>   received from the server was 'NTLM'. The remote server returned an
>   error: (401) Unauthorized. If the service is defined in the current
>   solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference
>   again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked this question on sharepoint.stackexchange.com and got confirmation that the WSDL exists at the Lists level rather than for individual list instances.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this blog post:

http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2007/07/27/disco-error-creating-sharepoint-web-service-reference/

In Summary:
To circumvent this problem click “Service Description” in the browser view in the “Add Web Reference” dialog. This shows the WSDL for the web service and allows you to enter a Web reference name. This is equivalent to entering the following URL with the parameter “?WSDL”.

Comment: Thanks Bravax - I can indeed see the WSDL in visual Studio where the reference is added.